# On Implode an array string not replaced

Tags: php, regex, replace

**I have an php string like that:**

```
$html = '<figure class="image article-image"><img alt="In Lebron-less era of the NBA, Pudenz makes the Miami Heat look like the Jordan-Era Chicago Bulls in this stunning and proficient blowout." src="https://image.jpg" caption="true"><br /> <figcaption>In Lebron-less era of the NBA, Pudenz makes the Miami Heat look like the Jordan-Era Chicago Bulls in this stunning and proficient blowout. To say "HES ON FIRE" would be an understatement.</figcaption><br /> </figure><br /> <p>This record is a tight one to say the least. Who doesnâ&#128;&#153;t know about the over-the-top basketball antics of <em>NBA Jam</em>? Winning a game isnâ&#128;&#153;t necessarily tough, but how much you can beat a computer controlled opponent by is a whole other story. <em>Jam</em> has some AI rubber banding mechanics that come into play to try to keep things fairn which a few opponent shots made it to their basket. All these things considered make this look like itâ&#128;&#153;s going to be a record worth watching as Pudenz claims king of the hill, yet remains hungry for more. Â </p><br /> <p><iframe width="100%" height="220" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" src="https://view.vzaar.com/13686906/player" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" allowtransparency="true" type="text/html" class="video-player" title="video player" name="vzvd-13686906" id="vzvd-13686906"></iframe></p><br /> <h2><strong><u>Arron Pitchford - <em>Game & Watch Gallery - Manhole</em> (Game Boy/Game Boy Color): Classic - Points</u></strong></h2><br /> <figure class="image article-image"><img alt="Pitchford takes the pains to make sure hundreds of little guys get safely to where they want to go, managing their frenzied and hectic moves across the bridges with incredible balance and efficiency." src="https://image1.jpg" caption="true"><br /> <figcaption>Pitchford takes the pains to make sure hundreds of little guys get safely to where they want to go, managing their frenzied and hectic moves across the bridges with incredible balance and efficiency.</figcaption><br /> </figure><br /> <p>Next we take a look at a handheld blast from the past. The <em>Game & Watch Gallery</em> was a fantastic collection of the grandfathers of all handheld gaming and <em>Manhole</em> is a great little look into the frantic nature of some of these games. p the task of bridging gaps in two structures for a d amassed an amazing 9,999 points, absolutely decimating the ssic-points/" target="_blank">previous record set on the leaderboard</a> back in 2017 (385 by s on how he could have gotten more points in his run, but with such a vast lead, he is content to sit at the top with what heâ&#128;&#153;s got for the time being. Fair enough, as it will take patience and dedication to dethrone him.</p><br /> <p><iframe width="100%" height="220" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" src="https://view.vzaar.com/13611958/player" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" allowtransparency="true" type="text/html" class="video-player" title="video player" name="vzvd-13611958" id="vzvd-13611958"></iframe></p><br /> <h2><strong><u>Angela Stefanski - <em>Burnout Revenge</em> (Xbox 360 - NTSC): Crash - Drain Damage (Dollars)</u></strong></h2><br /> <figure class="image article-image"><img alt="You think you know a good crash in Burnout? Stefanski puts on an explosive spectacle that makes this record a vehicular maelstrom of twisted metal." src="image2.jpg" caption="true"><br /> <figcaption>You think you know a good crash in Burnout? Stefanski puts on an explosive spectacle that makes this record a vehicular maelstrom of twisted metal.</figcaption><br /> </figure><br /> <p><em>Burnout</em> is a series most certainly known for its arcade and over-the-top racing, but anyone whoâ&#128;&#153;s gotten comfy behind the wheel of these wild games know the destruction and chaos one can sow in them. In this <em>Burnout Revenge</em> record, destruction to extremes. The atch Stefanskiâ&#128;&#153;s glorious appetite for destruction in this one.</p><br /> <p><iframe width="100%" height="220" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" src="https://view.vzaar.com/14078681/player" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" allowtransparency="true" type="text/html" class="video-player" title="video player" name="vzvd-14078681" id="vzvd-14078681"></iframe></p><br /> <h2><strong><u>Adam Hulbert - <em>Wizards of Wor</em> (Commodore 64 - Emulator): Points</u></strong></h2><br /> <figure class="image article-image"><img alt="Wizords of Wor has a ton of elements to manage if you want to lay claim to the title of Worlord Supreme. Hulbert handles the mess of monsters well to do just that." src="https://image3.jpg caption="true"><br /> <figcaption>Wizords of Wor has a ton of elements to manage if you want to lay claim to the title of Worlord Supreme. Hulbert handles the mess of monsters well to do just that.</figcaption><br /> </figure><br /> <p>This one takes us back into the Commodore 64 days with a little emulated play. tic mazes of <em>Wizards of Wor</em> to blast some beasties r 20 minutes. Itâ&#128;&#153;s enough to outdo the last <em>up a record of 148,900 back in 2016. Thereâ&#128;&#153;s a lot to consider for this run. The way the monsters move, your reflexes for killing them, and the monster that sets up double points for whole stages means players are going to need a little bit of luck and a lot of skill on their side if they want to challenge Hulbertâ&#128;&#153;s high score.</p><br /> <p><iframe width="100%" height="220" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" src="https://view.vzaar.com/13977536/player" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" allowtransparency="true" type="text/html" class="video-player" title="video player" name="vzvd-13977536" id="vzvd-13977536"></iframe></p><br /> <h2><strong><u>Donald Hayes - <em>Centipede</em> (Arcade): Points (Tournament Settings)</u></strong></h2><br /> <figure class="image article-image"><img alt="A video almost doesnt do it justice. Donald Hayes cold concentration and reflexes are a sight to be seen." src="https://image4.jpg" caption="true"><br /> <figcaption>A video almost doesnt do it justice. Donald Hayes cold concentration and reflexes are a sight to be seen.</figcaption><br /> </figure><br /> <p>This is a record we had the pleasure of seeing in person for itâ&#128;&#153;s massive entirety. Back at Score Wars at the end of March 2018 in Santa Fe, New Mexico,  act=8&ved=2ahUKEwiY2Jr0w9jaAhUl0YMKHTrJB_wQFjAAegQ IABAo&url=/score-wars-pro-galaga-tourney-results-andrew-barrow-becomes-world-champ&usg=AOvVaw0qW2LgK-QRX_vCzVxl7Bey" target="_blank">fantastic <em>Galaga</em> play</a> wasnâ&#128;&#153;t the only thing going on. Retro gaming pros were also making attempts at their own previously set records and achieving new heights. One of those pros was <em>Centipede</em> master dible marathon lasting nearly 10 hours, Hayes pursued his previous <em>et="_blank">Centipede high score</a></em> to set a new one and did when he finally blew his last life at an incredible 7,750,817 points. His previous record sat at 7,111,111 on the <em>gs Leaderboard</a></em>. We had a chance to talk to Hayes after the fact and ask him what it took to make a score like that. He kindly shared that much of the skill doesnâ&#128;&#153;t just land in moving fast, but also knowing where to stop.</p><br /> <p>â&#128;&#156;The control over the stop-and-go of the ship with the trackball is something I feel like I can tell you about all day,â&#128;&#157; Hayes claimed. â&#128;&#156;But itâ&#128;&#153;s also the sort of muscle memory and reflexes you canâ&#128;&#153;t teach with words. Itâ&#128;&#153;s what lets me get records like these and be able to say Iâ&#128;&#153;m the best at this.â&#128;&#157; Bold, but fair words from the champ, and a record that will take dedication and practice of an incredible level to match. To see Hayes in action was a pleasure, and this is a record more than earned.</p><br /> </p>';
```

**When I used it directly like that I got the result(replaced string):**

```
$changeimgoriarr = array('<img alt="In Lebron-less era of the NBA, Pudenz makes the Miami Heat look like the Jordan-Era Chicago Bulls in this stunning and proficient blowout." src="https://image.jpg" caption="true">','<img alt="Pitchford takes the pains to make sure hundreds of little guys get safely to where they want to go, managing their frenzied and hectic moves across the bridges with incredible balance and efficiency." src="https://image1.jpg" caption="true">','<img alt="You think you know a good crash in Burnout? Stefanski puts on an explosive spectacle that makes this record a vehicular maelstrom of twisted metal." src="image2.jpg" caption="true">','<img alt="Wizords of Wor has a ton of elements to manage if you want to lay claim to the title of Worlord Supreme. Hulbert handles the mess of monsters well to do just that." src="https://image3.jpg caption="true">','<img alt="A video almost doesnt do it justice. Donald Hayes cold concentration and reflexes are a sight to be seen." src="https://image4.jpg" caption="true">');

$changeimgnewarr = array('<a href="https://image.jpg"><img alt="In Lebron-less era of the NBA, Pudenz makes the Miami Heat look like the Jordan-Era Chicago Bulls in this stunning and proficient blowout." src="https://image.jpg" caption="true"></a>','<a href="https://image1.jpg"><img alt="Pitchford takes the pains to make sure hundreds of little guys get safely to where they want to go, managing their frenzied and hectic moves across the bridges with incredible balance and efficiency." src="https://image1.jpg" caption="true"></a>','<a href="image2.jpg"><img alt="You think you know a good crash in Burnout? Stefanski puts on an explosive spectacle that makes this record a vehicular maelstrom of twisted metal." src="image2.jpg" caption="true"></a>','<a href="https://image3.jpg><img alt="Wizords of Wor has a ton of elements to manage if you want to lay claim to the title of Worlord Supreme. Hulbert handles the mess of monsters well to do just that." src="https://image3.jpg caption="true"></a>','<a href="https://image4.jpg"><img alt="A video almost doesnt do it justice. Donald Hayes cold concentration and reflexes are a sight to be seen." src="https://image4.jpg" caption="true"></a>');

echo str_replace($changeimgoriarr, $changeimgnewarr, $html);
```

**Code For Getting image src values from the string :**

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]* src="https:\/\/[^>]*">/i', $html, $resultimg);

        $changesimgs = $resultimg[0];

        foreach ($changesimgs as $ckey => $cval) {
            $changeimgori[] = "'" .$cval ."'";
            preg_match('/"https:\/\/[^"]*"/i', $cval, $resultsrc);
            $changeimgnew[] = "'". '<a href=' . $resultsrc[0] . '>' . $cval . '</a>' ."'";
        }

        $changeimgnewarr = implode(',', $changeimgnew);
        $changeimgoriarr = implode(',', $changeimgori);
```

I got two arrays $changeimgoriarr & $changeimgnewarr

$changeimgoriarr = Is the original array values I got from current $html string;

$changeimgnewarr = String to be changes and created from the above code.

**I have checked the both arrays values I got from implode function :**

```
$changeimgoriarr = '<img alt="In Lebron-less era of the NBA, Pudenz makes the Miami Heat look like the Jordan-Era Chicago Bulls in this stunning and proficient blowout." src="https://image.jpg" caption="true">','<img alt="Pitchford takes the pains to make sure hundreds of little guys get safely to where they want to go, managing their frenzied and hectic moves across the bridges with incredible balance and efficiency." src="https://image1.jpg" caption="true">','<img alt="You think you know a good crash in Burnout? Stefanski puts on an explosive spectacle that makes this record a vehicular maelstrom of twisted metal." src="image2.jpg" caption="true">','<img alt="Wizords of Wor has a ton of elements to manage if you want to lay claim to the title of Worlord Supreme. Hulbert handles the mess of monsters well to do just that." src="https://image3.jpg caption="true">','<img alt="A video almost doesnt do it justice. Donald Hayes cold concentration and reflexes are a sight to be seen." src="https://image4.jpg" caption="true">';

$changeimgnewarr = '<a href="https://image.jpg"><img alt="In Lebron-less era of the NBA, Pudenz makes the Miami Heat look like the Jordan-Era Chicago Bulls in this stunning and proficient blowout." src="https://image.jpg" caption="true"></a>','<a href="https://image1.jpg"><img alt="Pitchford takes the pains to make sure hundreds of little guys get safely to where they want to go, managing their frenzied and hectic moves across the bridges with incredible balance and efficiency." src="https://image1.jpg" caption="true"></a>','<a href="image2.jpg"><img alt="You think you know a good crash in Burnout? Stefanski puts on an explosive spectacle that makes this record a vehicular maelstrom of twisted metal." src="image2.jpg" caption="true"></a>','<a href="https://image3.jpg><img alt="Wizords of Wor has a ton of elements to manage if you want to lay claim to the title of Worlord Supreme. Hulbert handles the mess of monsters well to do just that." src="https://image3.jpg caption="true"></a>','<a href="https://image4.jpg"><img alt="A video almost doesnt do it justice. Donald Hayes cold concentration and reflexes are a sight to be seen." src="https://image4.jpg" caption="true"></a>';
```

But on using string replace after it based on implode array not working:

```
echo str_replace(array($changeimgoriarr), ($changeimgnewarr), $html);
```

Please tell me what the issue in that why it is not working after imploded arrays.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you're trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: I would  I like to get result like:  that image tag src values inside anchor tag Example : <img src="htttps:..image.jpg"> I want like that <a href="https://image.jpg"><img src="https://image.jpg">

Comment: Are you trying to extract the values inside `src=""` and then add it as an `href=""`? Do you still need the `src` attribute then? Or would it be sufficient to just do `str_replace('src=', 'href=', $html);` (though you'd probably want to preg_replace this because of variants like `src = `)

Comment: What's the purpose of these single quotes `"'"` e.g. here: `$changeimgori[] = "'" .$cval ."'";` ?

Comment: I need src values also and add image tag in the anchor tag and the src value of image  tag in the href also. I need bot but In this way : <a href="https://image.jpg"><img src="https://image.jpg"></a>

Comment: `$changeimgori[] = "'" .$cval ."'";` pupose for that is only want values in seperated way. I have also tried remove that.

Comment: You may want to look into something like http://htmlparsing.com/php.html (using http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse and adjust the HTML. So you'd read in your HTML, then loop through all `img` tags, then get the the `src` from that element, and wrap the `img` in an `a` tag with the `href` parameter set. The benefit of something like this would be cleaner parsing of the HTML itself and not having to worry about single/double quotes, extra whitespace, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need the single quotes and you also don't need the implode part:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]* src="https:\/\/[^>]*">/i', $html, $resultimg);

$changesimgs = $resultimg[0];

$changeimgori = array();
$changeimgnew = array();

foreach ($changesimgs as $ckey => $cval) {
    $changeimgori[] = $cval;
    preg_match('/"https:\/\/[^"]*"/i', $cval, $resultsrc);
    $changeimgnew[] =  '<a href=' . $resultsrc[0] . '>' . $cval . '</a>';
}
echo str_replace($changeimgori, $changeimgnew, $html);
```

Comment: Thankyou I got the result...thankyou so much for response It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your code right, then you defined an array where you shouldn't have. I fixed the last line of code you posted :

```
echo str_replace($changeimgoriarr, $changeimgnewarr, $html);
```

str_replace replaces a string within a string, not arrays...

if you want your imploded strings back to arrays, then you should use explode :

```
$orgarr = array();
$orgarr = explode(',', $changeimgoriarr);

$newarr = array();
$newarr = explode(',', $changeimgnewarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to achieve what I think you're looking for using PHP's DOM classes (http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). This should be more resilient than string replaces and preg matching because it's node-based:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $image) {
    $a = $dom->createElement('a'); //create new <a>
    $a->setAttribute('href', $image->getAttribute('src')); //set a's href to image's src

    $image->parentNode->insertBefore($a, $image); //insert <a>
    $image->parentNode->removeChild($image); //remove <img>

    $a->appendChild($image); //set <img> as child of <a>
}
$output = $dom->saveHTML();

echo $output;
```